# Loop over distinct combinations of 3 pins

Tags: algorithm, combinations

I'm working with 3 LED's and I'd like to write some concise code to loop through all distinct combinations of the 3.

```
i.e. 0=Red led, 1=blue, 2=green
000 = Red
001 = 011 = ... = 110 = Red + Blue
002
012
111
112
222
```

There are only 7 combinations but i'm stuck with the pseudo code below

```
allcombos()
    for(i=0 to 2)
        for(j=i to 2)
            turnOn(i,j)
            delay
            turnOff
            delay
    turnOn(0,1,2)
    delay
    turnOff
    delay
```

The for loops handle all 2 LED combos without repetition but I've had to add a special case for all 3.

I keep looking at the code and thinking their might be a way I can nest another loop to catch that case (I realize there is nothing to gain from this). More of an exercise than anything else. Or perhaps there is a recursive way to do this?

Comment: You seem to be speaking of permutations with replacement, of which there are 27. Needs clarification.

Comment: I'm speaking of the exact 7 combinations I wrote down. There is no difference between the statements "turnOn(1,0,0)" and "turnOn(0,1,1)" in either case the red and blue LEDs turn on.

Comment: I don't think I understand the system here. You say "001 = 011 = ... = 110 = Red + Blue", but you also say "1=blue". How can 1 be both "blue" and "Red + Blue"?

Comment: Do you have one red LED, one blue LED, and one green LED? Or do you have three LEDS, each of which can display any primary color?

Comment: one red, one blue and one green. the 0,1,2 indicates the pin number where the LED is. i.e. 001 == red, red, blue. My set of combinations could be rewritten (0,1,2,01,02,12,012).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend a different approach (C-ish pseudocode):

```
for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
{ if (i & 1)
    turnOn(0)
  if (i & 2)
    turnOn(1)
  if (i & 4)
    turnOn(2)
  delay
  turnOff
}
```

Comment: if this is C-ish, would that be a bitwise &?

Comment: @user3817250 Exactly - each `if ()` tests to see if one specific bit is on or not...

Comment: I had to make one adjustment to this. setting i=1 at the beginning of the loop avoids the case where nothing gets turned on.